# check uncheck functionality in prototype.js in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, prototype-js

There is a label `(class=lblnewsletter)` and checkbox `(id=is_subscribed)`.
When I click on label and if the checkbox is checked the alert will come 111 other wise it return 222.
I have wrote the following code but not working.
Please help.

```
$$('.lblnewsletter')[0].observe('click', function () {

    if($$('#is_subscribed').checked){
        alert(111);
   }else{
        alert(222);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have id then used that

```
  $('is_subscribed').observe('click', function () {

    if($('is_subscribed').checked){
        alert(111);
   }else{
        alert(222);
   }
});
```

Comment: As per requirement that solution is ok. But now I am implementing the function as below:

Comment: $$('#is_subscribed')[0].observe('click', function () {
    if($$('#is_subscribed').checked){
        $$('.lblnewsletter').addClassName('chked');
   }else{
        $$('.lblnewsletter').removeClassName('chked');
   }
});

Comment: you are mixing the jquery and prototype.

Comment: But it shows an error "TypeError: $$(...).removeClassName is not a function"

Comment: please solve it

Comment: `$('is_subscribed').observe('click', function () { if($('is_subscribed').checked){  $('is_subscribed').addClassName('chked'); }else{ $('is_subscribed').removeClassName('chked'); } }); ` use this

Comment: Inside of the observer function you can refer to `this` as the element being  observed eg ```$('is_subscribed').observe('click', function () { if(this.checked){ this.addClassName('chked'); }else{ this.removeClassName('chked'); } });``` which actually saves element lookups and is easier to maintain or make portable